# Using DataPager with Repeater and SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to have custom paging with **Next** and **Prev** and page numbers between them for `Repeater` (like `GridView`)? I found something but it works for 10 pages only.
What I want is like this, something like **google** does for paging:

```
< 1 2 3 4 ... 15 >
```

I found out extending `Repeater` let me use DataPager, explained here: [CodeProject: Extend Repeater to support `DataPager`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45163/Extend-Repeater-to-support-DataPager)
But when I use `SqlDataReader` as `DataSource` I face this error:

```
Type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' in Assembly 
    'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.
```

It's my code:

```
public bool ListBooksByCat(DataPagerRepeater.DataPagerRepeater repeater)
{
    List<string> selection = new List<string>();
    Dictionary<string, object> clause = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    clause.Add("IsValid", true);
    SqlDB myDb = new SqlDB(this.Connection);

    try
    {
        SqlDataReader reader = myDb.Retrive(this.TableName, selection, clause, "bookid", true);
        repeater.DataSource = reader;
        repeater.DataBind();
        reader.Close();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //logging errors
        return false;
    }
}
```

`Note`: DataPagerRepeater.DataPagerRepeater is built in linked article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than binding to the SqlReader you should bind your control to DataTable or some other collection which take data offline(DataReader always remain in connected mode during binding). You're getting this error  because the SqlDataReader is a resource related object and any resource-related object cannot be "passed" to a client.

Answer (score 0):

I copied `SqlDataReader` to a `DataTable` then bind the repeater to it:

```
    SqlDataReader reader = myDb.Retrive(this.TableName, selection, clause, "bookid", true);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(reader);
    reader.Close();
    repeater.DataSource = dt;
    repeater.DataBind();
```